# QVector para QImage

Tags: c++, qt, conversão-de-tipo, imagem, pgm

Tenho de transformar um `QVector` 2d em um `QImage` para apresentar em um label a imagem. O `QVector` no caso é um array de inteiros com valor de 0 a 255 representando uma imagem em PGM ou PPM, este vetor faço transformações na escala de cinza ou RGB que são necessárias aos exercícios de PDI, porem para facilitar um pouco e tornar os métodos genéricos mais fáceis de se utilizar decidi colocar a imagem em um QImage e apresentar as alterações.

A duvida é como posso transportar os `QVector<QVector<int> >` para o `QImage`, onde possa ainda adicionar as informações de formato de arquivo, no caso `P2` e `P3`, linha de comentário, número de linhas e colunas e escala de cor.

Seria algo como isto:

```
P2
# Comentário do arquivo
número de linhas  número de colunas
255
vetor 2d com as informações da imagem.
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode converter o seu `QVector<QVector<int> >` para o formato de PGM em `const char*` e deixar que o Qt faça o resto, pois o `QImage` suporta PGM.

### Exemplo:

No seu caso é só substituir o `pgm_file` pelo que será gerado pelo seu `QVector`.

```
const char* pgm_file =
        "P2\n"
        "# Exemplo\n"
        "24 7\n"
        "15\n"
        "0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n"
        "0  3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15 15 15 15  0\n"
        "0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 15  0\n"
        "0  3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7  7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0  0  0 15 15 15 15  0\n"
        "0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0\n"
        "0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15  0  0  0  0\n"
        "0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n";

QByteArray bytes(pgm_file);

QImage img;
img.loadFromData(bytes, "PGM"); // Pronto. Tá convertido.

// Se quiser ver o resultado.
img.save("resultado.bmp", "BMP");
```

Imagem convertida:
[image: Imagem Convertida]